# Hi! Want to add a browser plugin in python (Should work on all browsers -- expected)

Tags: python, browser-plugin

The plugin will map unicode to letters of a language! That is my requirement, for that I want to start with some basic plugin (Example "Hello World!" program) that is running in the browser! Please help me with some references/code or any resources!!

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You don t need to make a browser plugin for that, it would only make your work harder. Browser plugins are needed when you want to change the behavior of the browser for example. What you want to do is called a web app. Write your code in Python for now, and then learn how to use [Brython](http://www.brython.info/). Also learn basic html.

Comment: I want this to be enabled in the browser so that it can be used in any web page (Unicode - letter converter)! Sorry if I am too basic!. does brython + html solve this???